# Error converting month number to datetime object

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, datetime

Trying to convert a column in a dataframe from the months 1-420 (35 years of monthly data from 1985 to 2010) to a datetime object.

Sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.Series(range(1,421))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(420,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Convert index to a datetime object:

```
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index,unit='M', origin='1981-01-01')
```

Gives the error:

```
ValueError: cannot cast unit M
```

I don't know why it won't cast the unit M, as when I try 'd' instead of 'M' it works, and goes up daily - why won't it go up monthly? I got the units from [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

using 'm' output looks like this:

```
                       A           B            C            D
1981-01-01 00:01:00 0.672397    0.753926    0.865845    0.711594
1981-01-01 00:02:00 0.786754    0.658421    -0.111609   -1.459447
1981-01-01 00:03:00 0.200273    -1.485525   -1.939203   0.921833
1981-01-01 00:04:00 -1.589668   0.109760    -1.349790   -1.951316
1981-01-01 00:05:00 0.133847    -0.359300   -1.246740   -0.835645
1981-01-01 00:06:00 -0.843962   1.222129    -0.121450   -1.223132
1981-01-01 00:07:00 -0.818932   0.731127    0.984731    -1.028384
```

which goes up in minutes, I want it to go up in Months like this:

```
                            A           B            C           D
    1981-01-01 00:00:00 0.672397    0.753926    0.865845    0.711594
    1981-02-01 00:00:00 0.786754    0.658421    -0.111609   -1.459447
    1981-03-01 00:00:00 0.200273    -1.485525   -1.939203   0.921833
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @harv I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

You should use [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html):

```
df2.index = pd.date_range('1981/1/1', periods=len(df2), freq='MS')
```

Output:

```
                A           B           C            D
1981-01-01  -0.761933   0.726808    0.589712    -1.170934
1981-02-01  0.030521    -0.892427   -1.366809   -1.515724
1981-03-01  -0.282887   1.068047    0.244493    -0.247356
```

Have a look at [offset alias](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) for more information.

EDIT: As OP said, the 425 days are repeating over 200,000 rows. Below code would provide repeated indices.

```
daterange = pd.date_range('1981/1/1', periods=420, freq='MS')
```

Then expand it to fit your dataframe by repeating it.

```
df2.index = list(daterange) * math.floor(len(df2)/len(list(daterange))) + list(daterange)[0:math.floor(len(df2)%len(list(daterange)))]
```

Comment: This goes up in minutes, not months, when I try the capital M for months, it gives the same error

Comment: This works for this sample data, but not for my actual data - for my actual data I need to convert a column containing the numbers from 1:420 to a column from 01/01/1981 to 01/12/2015. This doesn't work for it as I get the error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`. It doesn't match the length of the index as the index is 200,000 rows long, but the numbers 1-420 are recurring throughout. I need to convert each 1 to 01/01/1981, each 2 to 01/02/1981 etc. This works when I do the datetime argument for days, but not months.

Comment: It seems like this functionality [has been deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16344)

Comment: @Pad You are right. Although, there is a work around of it. I tried your problem with more than 420 rows. This gives me a repeating index. try this. Let me know if it works. Get a list of objects that you would like to repeat. `daterange = pd.date_range('1981/1/1', periods=420, freq='MS')` Then expand it to fit your dataframe by repeating it. `df2.index = list(daterange) * math.floor(len(df2)/len(list(daterange))) + list(daterange)[0:math.floor(len(df2)%len(list(daterange)))] `

Comment: thank you - sorry I am only seeing this now as I was away from wifi. When I try and apply what you have done to the column in my dataframe I get the error `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` - when I try convert to int it gives more errors!